# ExpressJS How to structure an application?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using the ExpressJS web framework for NodeJS.

People using ExpressJS put their environments (development, production, test...), their routes etc on the `app.js`. I think that it's not a beautiful way because when you have a big application, app.js is too big!

I would like to have this directory structure:

```
| my-application
| -- app.js
| -- config/
     | -- environment.js
     | -- routes.js
```

Here's my code:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

require('./config/environment.js')(app, express);
require('./config/routes.js')(app);

app.listen(3000);
```

**config/environment.js**

```
module.exports = function(app, express){
    app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.logger());
    });

    app.configure('development', function() {
    app.use(express.errorHandler({
        dumpExceptions: true,
        showStack: true
    }));
    });

    app.configure('production', function() {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
    });
};
```

**config/routes.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello world !');
    });
};
```

My code works well and I think that the structure of the directories is beautiful. However, the code had to be adapted and I'm not sure that it's good/beautiful.

Is it better to use my structure of directories and adapt the code or simply use one file (app.js)?

Thanks for your advices!

Comment: Are the performance issues of doing it this way still lurking around? I remember reading somewhere (maybe the express group) that when you separate everything like this you lose a ton of performance. Something like your reqs/sec will drop by a noticeable amount, almost as if it were a bug.

Comment: It was from the Express Google group. Here's the link:

http://groups.google.com/group/express-js/browse_thread/thread/5b2595de689e566a/76543695a4e23633?#76543695a4e23633

Comment: nope this is very untrue

Comment: https://github.com/rahulshukla-rs/node-express-mongodb-folder-structure-with-auth

Comment: [Node Best Practices](https://github.com/goldbergyoni/nodebestpractices#1-project-structure-practices) on Github recommends grouping by feature.

Comment: Hi All,

In which folder I have to place the logger (winston)

i.e

src/logger
src/utils

Please suggest

Answer (score 353, accepted):

OK, it's been a while and this is a popular question, so I've gone ahead and created a scaffolding github repository with JavaScript code and a long README about how I like to structure a medium-sized express.js application.

[focusaurus/express_code_structure](https://github.com/focusaurus/express_code_structure) is the repo with the latest code for this. Pull requests welcome.

Here's a snapshot of the README since stackoverflow doesn't like just-a-link answers. I'll make some updates as this is a new project that I'll continue updating, but ultimately the github repo will be the up-to-date place for this information.

---

#Express Code Structure

This project is an example of how to organize a medium-sized express.js web application.

**Current to at least express v4.14 December 2016**

[image: Build Status]

[image: js-standard-style]

### How big is your application?

Web applications are not all the same, and there's not, in my opinion, a single code structure that should be applied to all express.js applications.

If your application is small, you don't need such a deep directory structure as exemplified here. Just keep it simple and stick a handful of `.js` files in the root of your repository and you're done. Voilà.

If your application is huge, at some point you need to break it up into distinct npm packages. In general the node.js approach seems to favor many small packages, at least for libraries, and you should build your application up by using several npm packages as that starts to make sense and justify the overhead. So as your application grows and some portion of the code becomes clearly reusable outside of your application or is a clear subsystem, move it to its own git repository and make it into a standalone npm package.

**So** the focus of this project is to illustrate a workable structure for a medium-sized application.

### What is your overall architecture

There are many approaches to building a web application, such as

- Server Side MVC a la Ruby on Rails
- Single Page Application style a la MongoDB/Express/Angular/Node (MEAN)
- Basic web site with some forms
- Models/Operations/Views/Events style a la [MVC is dead, it's time to MOVE on](http://cirw.in/blog/time-to-move-on.html)
- and many others both current and historical

Each of these fits nicely into a different directory structure. For the purposes of this example, it's just scaffolding and not a fully working app, but I'm assuming the following key architecture points:

- The site has some traditional static pages/templates
- The "application" portion of the site is developed as a Single Page Application style
- The application exposes a REST/JSON style API to the browser
- The app models a simple business domain, in this case, it's a car dealership application

### And what about Ruby on Rails?

It will be a theme throughout this project that many of the ideas embodied in Ruby on Rails and the "Convention over Configuration" decisions they have adopted, though widely accepted and used, are not actually very helpful and sometimes are the opposite of what this repository recommends.

My main point here is that there are underlying principles to organizing code, and based on those principles, the Ruby on Rails conventions make sense (mostly) for the Ruby on Rails community. However, just thoughtlessly aping those conventions misses the point. Once you grok the basic principles, ALL of your projects will be well-organized and clear: shell scripts, games, mobile apps, enterprise projects, even your home directory.

For the Rails community, they want to be able to have a single Rails developer switch from app to app to app and be familiar and comfortable with it each time. This makes great sense if you are 37 signals or Pivotal Labs, and has benefits. In the server-side JavaScript world, the overall ethos is just way more wild west anything goes and we don't really have a problem with that. That's how we roll. We're used to it. Even within express.js, it's a close kin of Sinatra, not Rails, and taking conventions from Rails is usually not helping anything. I'd even say **Principles over Convention over Configuration**.

### Underlying Principles and Motivations

- Be mentally manageable

  - The brain can only deal with and think about a small number of related things at once. That's why we use directories. It helps us deal with complexity by focusing on small portions.
- Be size-appropriate

  - Don't create "Mansion Directories" where there's just 1 file all alone 3 directories down. You can see this happening in the [Ansible Best Practices](http://www.ansibleworks.com/docs/playbooks_best_practices.html) that shames small projects into creating 10+ directories to hold 10+ files when 1 directory with 3 files would be much more appropriate. You don't drive a bus to work (unless you're a bus driver, but even then your driving a bus AT work not TO work), so don't create filesystem structures that aren't justified by the actual files inside them.
- Be modular but pragmatic

  - The node community overall favors small modules. Anything that can cleanly be separated out from your app entirely should be extracted into a module either for internal use or publicly published on npm. However, for the medium-sized applications that are the scope here, the overhead of this can add tedium to your workflow without commensurate value. So for the time when you have some code that is factored out but not enough to justify a completely separate npm module, just consider it a "**proto-module**" with the expectation that when it crosses some size threshold, it would be extracted out.
  - Some folks such as [@hij1nx](https://twitter.com/hij1nx) even include an `app/node_modules` directory and have `package.json` files in the **proto-module** directories to facilitate that transition and act as a reminder.
- Be easy to locate code

  - Given a feature to build or a bug to fix, our goal is that a developer has no struggle locating the source files involved.

    - Names are meaningful and accurate
    - crufty code is fully removed, not left around in an orphan file or just commented out
- Be search-friendly

  - all first-party source code is in the `app` directory so you can `cd` there are run find/grep/xargs/ag/ack/etc and not be distracted by third party matches
- Use simple and obvious naming

  - npm now seems to require all-lowercase package names. I find this mostly terrible but I must follow the herd, thus filenames should use `kebab-case` even though the variable name for that in JavaScript must be `camelCase` because `-` is a minus sign in JavaScript.
  - variable name matches the basename of the module path, but with `kebab-case` transformed to `camelCase`
- Group by Coupling, Not by Function

  - This is a major departure from the Ruby on Rails convention of `app/views`, `app/controllers`, `app/models`, etc
  - Features get added to a full stack, so I want to focus on a full stack of files that are relevant to my feature. When I'm adding a telephone number field to the user model, I don't care about any controller other than the user controller, and I don't care about any model other than the user model.
  - So instead of editing 6 files that are each in their own directory and ignoring tons of other files in those directories, this repository is organized such that all the files I need to build a feature are colocated
  - By the nature of MVC, the user view is coupled to the user controller which is coupled to the user model. So when I change the user model, those 3 files will often change together, but the deals controller or customer controller are decoupled and thus not involved. Same applies to non-MVC designs usually as well.
  - MVC or MOVE style decoupling in terms of which code goes in which module is still encouraged, but spreading the MVC files out into sibling directories is just annoying.
  - Thus each of my routes files has the portion of the routes it owns. A rails-style `routes.rb` file is handy if you want an overview of all routes in the app, but when actually building features and fixing bugs, you only care about the routes relevant to the piece you are changing.
- Store tests next to the code

  - This is just an instance of "group by coupling", but I wanted to call it out specifically. I've written many projects where the tests live under a parallel filesystem called "tests" and now that I've started putting my tests in the same directory as their corresponding code, I'm never going back. This is more modular and much easier to work with in text editors and alleviates a lot of the "../../.." path nonsense. If you are in doubt, try it on a few projects and decide for yourself. I'm not going to do anything beyond this to convince you that it's better.
- Reduce cross-cutting coupling with Events

  - It's easy to think "OK, whenever a new Deal is created, I want to send an email to all the Salespeople", and then just put the code to send those emails in the route that creates deals.
  - However, this coupling will eventually turn your app into a giant ball of mud.
  - Instead, the DealModel should just fire a "create" event and be entirely unaware of what else the system might do in response to that.
  - When you code this way, it becomes much more possible to put all the user related code into `app/users` because there's not a rat's nest of coupled business logic all over the place polluting the purity of the user code base.
- Code flow is followable

  - Don't do magic things. Don't autoload files from magic directories in the filesystem. Don't be Rails. The app starts at `app/server.js:1` and you can see everything it loads and executes by following the code.
  - Don't make DSLs for your routes. Don't do silly metaprogramming when it is not called for.
  - If your app is so big that doing `magicRESTRouter.route(somecontroller, {except: 'POST'})` is a big win for you over 3 basic `app.get`, `app.put`, `app.del`, calls, you're probably building a monolithic app that is too big to effectively work on. Get fancy for BIG wins, not for converting 3 simple lines to 1 complex line.
- Use lower-kebab-case filenames

  - This format avoids filesystem case sensitivity issues across platforms
  - npm forbids uppercase in new package names, and this works well with that

### express.js specifics

- Don't use `app.configure`. It's almost entirely useless and you just don't need it. It is in lots of boilerplate due to mindless copypasta.
- THE ORDER OF MIDDLEWARE AND ROUTES IN EXPRESS MATTERS!!!

  - Almost every routing problem I see on stackoverflow is out-of-order express middleware
  - In general, you want your routes decoupled and not relying on order that much
  - Don't use `app.use` for your entire application if you really only need that middleware for 2 routes (I'm looking at you, `body-parser`)
  - Make sure when all is said and done you have EXACTLY this order:

    1. Any super-important application-wide middleware
    2. All your routes and assorted route middlewares
    3. THEN error handlers
- Sadly, being sinatra-inspired, express.js mostly assumes all your routes will be in `server.js` and it will be clear how they are ordered. For a medium-sized application, breaking things out into separate routes modules is nice, but it does introduce peril of out-of-order middleware

### The app symlink trick

There are many approaches outlined and discussed at length by the community in the great gist [Better local require() paths for Node.js](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520). I may soon decide to prefer either "just deal with lots of ../../../.." or use the [requireFrom](https://github.com/DSKrepps/requireFrom) modlue. However, at the moment, I've been using the symlink trick detailed below.

So one way to avoid intra-project requires with annoying relative paths like `require("../../../config")` is to use the following trick:

- create a symlink under node_modules for your app

  - cd node_modules && ln -nsf ../app
- add **just the node_modules/app symlink itself**, not the entire node_modules folder, to git

  - git add -f node_modules/app
  - Yes, you should still have "node_modules" in your `.gitignore` file
  - No, you should not put "node_modules" into your git repository. Some people will recommend you do this. They are incorrect.
- Now you can require intra-project modules using this prefix

  - `var config = require("app/config");`
  - `var DealModel = require("app/deals/deal-model")`;
- Basically, this makes intra-project requires work very similarly to requires for external npm modules.
- Sorry, Windows users, you need to stick with parent directory relative paths.

### Configuration

Generally code modules and classes to expect only a basic JavaScript `options` object passed in. Only `app/server.js` should load the `app/config.js` module. From there it can synthesize small `options` objects to configure subsystems as needed, but coupling every subsystem to a big global config module full of extra information is bad coupling.

Try to centralize creation of DB connections and pass those into subsystems as opposed to passing connection parameters and having subsystems make outgoing connections themselves.

#### NODE_ENV

This is another enticing but terrible idea carried over from Rails. There should be exactly 1 place in your app, `app/config.js` that looks at the `NODE_ENV` environment variable. Everything else should take an explicit option as a class constructor argument or module configuration parameter.

If the email module has an option as to how to deliver emails (SMTP, log to stdout, put in queue etc), it should take an option like `{deliver: 'stdout'}` but it should absolutely not check `NODE_ENV`.

### Tests

I now keep my test files in the same directory as their corresponding code and use filename extension naming conventions to distinguish tests from production code.

- `foo.js` has the module "foo"'s code
- `foo.tape.js` has the node-based tests for foo and lives in the same dir
- `foo.btape.js` can be used for tests that need to execute in a browser environment

I use filesystem globs and the `find . -name '*.tape.js'` command to get access to all my tests as necessary.

### How to organize code within each `.js` module file

This project's scope is mostly about where files and directories go, and I don't want to add much other scope, but I'll just mention that I organize my code into 3 distinct sections.

1. Opening block of CommonJS require calls to state dependencies
2. Main code block of pure-JavaScript. No CommonJS pollution in here. Don't reference exports, module, or require.
3. Closing block of CommonJS to set up exports

Comment: What should I use instead of bodyParser If I have only few routes that uses it?

Comment: I found what I was looking for here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418372/node-js-express-correct-use-of-bodyparser-middleware/12418799#12418799

Comment: @wlingke check out https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520 for a thorough discussion of available approaches to that problem.

Comment: @peterLyons Thanks for sharing that. After reading through, I think I'll write a startup script. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, just stumbled upon this. Thanks for putting it together. One question, what is the purpose of `var AUTOUSING_THE_ROUTER_IS_A_NUISANCE = app.router;`? I've looked through the README but couldn't figure out how this applies to ordering. Thanks. Reference: https://github.com/focusaurus/express_code_structure/blob/master/app/server.js#L14

Comment: There was a confusing/magical nuisance in express 3.x where simply accessing the `app.router` property would add it to your middleware chain. They are thankfully fixing this in express 4. See https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x#approuter

Comment: So true. I agree with everything you mentioned. Most MVC libraries like cakephp(ugh) require making a folder for even a single file.
And no, this does not scale well for a large app.

Comment: I disagree with "I don't know why people do `var myModule = require("my-module");`. It's just silly. Don't put minus signs in filesystem paths or package names.". 

Some file systems are case sensitive and some are not, which means camelCase files are prone to user error across O/S's ie. occasionally forgetting to camelCase the file and still `require('camelCase.js')`.

Angular follows the hyphen-casing to camelCase convention for it's directive definition in html and the subsequent DI in js.

AFAIK this is the node convention.

Thoughts?

Comment: @PeterLyons, could you explain this silly thing? ;) https://github.com/focusaurus/express_code_structure/blob/master/app/customers/router.js#L1 I like the minus sign naming, no problem with that.  Once one of my favorite good ol framework went to camelcase file naming, I didn't noticed on windows. Guess how went the deploy to a linux server... :D

Comment: How do you name the folders "grouped by coupling" though? Can I express "grouped by coupling" as "grouped by feature"? Can different features reuse same models? If I group "authentication" and "CRUD account" under the same folder, what should I name it?

Comment: Authentication is typically a cross-cutting, application-wide concern and therefore should not be stored within a directory specific to a particular model. If you can imagine successfully changing your authentication logic while leaving your CRUD account logic unchanged, they don't belong in the same directory. Generally I'd name my model-specific folders the plural of the model like `app/accounts`.

Comment: But authentication still requires the present of Account model. Should I split it into a separate folder and require the Account model like `require('../accounts/account-model')`

Comment: That's fine but I'd probably have `app/auth.js` sitting in the top-level `app` 
 directory do a `require('./accounts/account-model');` as I think `../` in a require is usually but not always a code smell indicating poor organization boundaries.

Comment: with regards to the **The app symlink trick**, there's [this](https://github.com/ilearnio/module-alias) little module which makes all the problems go away

Answer (score 157):

**UPDATE (2013-10-29)**: Please see my other answer as well which has JavaScript instead of CoffeeScript by popular demand as well as a boilerplate github repo and an extensive README detailing my latest recommendations on this topic.

**Config**

What you are doing is fine.  I like to have my own config namespace set up in a top-level `config.coffee` file with a nested namespace like this.

```
#Set the current environment to true in the env object
currentEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV or 'development'
exports.appName = "MyApp"
exports.env =
  production: false
  staging: false
  test: false
  development: false
exports.env[currentEnv] = true
exports.log =
  path: __dirname + "/var/log/app_#{currentEnv}.log"
exports.server =
  port: 9600
  #In staging and production, listen loopback. nginx listens on the network.
  ip: '127.0.0.1'
if currentEnv not in ['production', 'staging']
  exports.enableTests = true
  #Listen on all IPs in dev/test (for testing from other machines)
  exports.server.ip = '0.0.0.0'
exports.db =
  URL: "mongodb://localhost:27017/#{exports.appName.toLowerCase()}_#{currentEnv}"
```

This is friendly for sysadmin editing.  Then when I need something, like the DB connection info, it`s

```
require('./config').db.URL
```

**Routes/Controllers**

I like to leave my routes with my controllers and organize them in an `app/controllers` subdirectory.  Then I can load them up and let them add whatever routes they need.

In my `app/server.coffee` coffeescript file I do:

```
[
  'api'
  'authorization'
  'authentication'
  'domains'
  'users'
  'stylesheets'
  'javascripts'
  'tests'
  'sales'
].map (controllerName) ->
  controller = require './controllers/' + controllerName
  controller.setup app
```

So I have files like:

```
app/controllers/api.coffee
app/controllers/authorization.coffee
app/controllers/authentication.coffee
app/controllers/domains.coffee
```

And for example in my domains controller, I have a `setup` function like this.

```
exports.setup = (app) ->
  controller = new exports.DomainController
  route = '/domains'
  app.post route, controller.create
  app.put route, api.needId
  app.delete route, api.needId
  route = '/domains/:id'
  app.put route, controller.loadDomain, controller.update
  app.del route, controller.loadDomain, exports.delete
  app.get route, controller.loadDomain, (req, res) ->
    res.sendJSON req.domain, status.OK
```

**Views**

Putting views in `app/views` is becoming the customary place.  I lay it out like this.

```
app/views/layout.jade
app/views/about.jade
app/views/user/EditUser.jade
app/views/domain/EditDomain.jade
```

**Static Files**

Go in a `public` subdirectory.

**Github/Semver/NPM**

Put a README.md markdown file at your git repo root for github.

Put a package.json file with a [semantic version](http://semver.org/) number in your git repo root for NPM.

Comment: Hey Peter ! I really like this approach you're going for. I'm working on building on an express project and I'd really want to do things the right way than just to hack it up and put it around.
Would be superb if you had a sample repo on github and/or a blog post on it.

Comment: This repo has a bunch of patterns you can use as a reference: https://github.com/focusaurus/peterlyons.com

Comment: Coffee script make this hard to read :/ Any chance to get a vanilla JS edit? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm just trying to wrap my mind around it. How do you access the other controllers inside another (e.g. in the setup function like the above ````app.put route, api.needId````

Comment: @PeterLyons: hey man, i did see your source code but have no idea how to do the build mode, I've already installed `Go` and include the `bin` file into the structure. How do you run that `go` file in `bin`?

Comment: @grasGendarme, I adapted this to vanilla JS - see my answer below.

Comment: I'am new to Node and am trying to understand the full context of the setup method. Also this part `controller = new exports.DomainController`, why exactly DomainController is prefixed with `exports`?

Comment: In that file I've only defined the `DomainController` constructor function as a property of the `exports` object, so I need that prefix to refer to it properly. Defining it as a property of `exports` makes it available to code outside the file. It's part of the CommonJS module system that node.js uses. Note there's a version of this answer coded in regular JavaScript which you should probably refer to as the CoffeeScript fad has ended.

Answer (score 53):

The following is Peter Lyons' answer verbatim, ported over to vanilla JS from Coffeescript, as requested by several others. Peter's answer is very able, and anyone voting on my answer should vote on his as well.

---

**Config**

What you are doing is fine.  I like to have my own config namespace set up in a top-level `config.js` file with a nested namespace like this.

```
// Set the current environment to true in the env object
var currentEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
exports.appName = "MyApp";
exports.env = {
  production: false,
  staging: false,
  test: false,
  development: false
};  
exports.env[currentEnv] = true;
exports.log = {
  path: __dirname + "/var/log/app_#{currentEnv}.log"
};  
exports.server = {
  port: 9600,
  // In staging and production, listen loopback. nginx listens on the network.
  ip: '127.0.0.1'
};  
if (currentEnv != 'production' && currentEnv != 'staging') {
  exports.enableTests = true;
  // Listen on all IPs in dev/test (for testing from other machines)
  exports.server.ip = '0.0.0.0';
};
exports.db {
  URL: "mongodb://localhost:27017/#{exports.appName.toLowerCase()}_#{currentEnv}"
};
```

This is friendly for sysadmin editing.  Then when I need something, like the DB connection info, it`s

```
require('./config').db.URL
```

**Routes/Controllers**

I like to leave my routes with my controllers and organize them in an `app/controllers` subdirectory.  Then I can load them up and let them add whatever routes they need.

In my `app/server.js` javascript file I do:

```
[
  'api',
  'authorization',
  'authentication',
  'domains',
  'users',
  'stylesheets',
  'javascripts',
  'tests',
  'sales'
].map(function(controllerName){
  var controller = require('./controllers/' + controllerName);
  controller.setup(app);
});
```

So I have files like:

```
app/controllers/api.js
app/controllers/authorization.js
app/controllers/authentication.js
app/controllers/domains.js
```

And for example in my domains controller, I have a `setup` function like this.

```
exports.setup = function(app) {
  var controller = new exports.DomainController();
  var route = '/domains';
  app.post(route, controller.create);
  app.put(route, api.needId);
  app.delete(route, api.needId);
  route = '/domains/:id';
  app.put(route, controller.loadDomain, controller.update);
  app.del(route, controller.loadDomain, function(req, res){
    res.sendJSON(req.domain, status.OK);
  });
}
```

**Views**

Putting views in `app/views` is becoming the customary place.  I lay it out like this.

```
app/views/layout.jade
app/views/about.jade
app/views/user/EditUser.jade
app/views/domain/EditDomain.jade
```

**Static Files**

Go in a `public` subdirectory.

**Github/Semver/NPM**

Put a README.md markdown file at your git repo root for github.

Put a package.json file with a [semantic version](http://semver.org/) number in your git repo root for NPM.

Answer (score 50):

My question was introduced in April 2011, it's quiet old. During this time, I could improve my experience with Express.js and how to architecture an application written using this library. So, I share here my experience.

Here's my directory structure:

```
├── app.js   // main entry
├── config   // The configuration of my applications (logger, global config, ...)
├── models   // The model data (e.g. Mongoose model)
├── public   // The public directory (client-side code)
├── routes   // The route definitions and implementations
├── services // The standalone services (Database service, Email service, ...)
└── views    // The view rendered by the server to the client (e.g. Jade, EJS, ...)
```

**App.js**

The goal of the `app.js` file is to bootstrap the expressjs application. It loads the configuration module, the logger module, wait for database connection, ..., and run the express server.

```
'use strict';
require('./config');
var database = require('./services/database');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
module.exports = app;

function main() {
  var http = require('http');

  // Configure the application.
  app.configure(function () {
    // ... ... ...
  });
  app.configure('production', function () {
    // ... ... ...
  });
  app.configure('development', function () {
    // ... ... ...
  });

  var server = http.createServer(app);

  // Load all routes.
  require('./routes')(app);

  // Listen on http port.
  server.listen(3000);
}

database.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) { 
    // ...
  }
  main();
});
```

**routes/**

The routes directory has a `index.js` file. Its goal is to introduce a kind of magic to load  all other files inside the `routes/` directory. Here's the implementation:

```
/**
 * This module loads dynamically all routes modules located in the routes/
 * directory.
 */
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function (app) {
  fs.readdirSync('./routes').forEach(function (file) {
    // Avoid to read this current file.
    if (file === path.basename(__filename)) { return; }

    // Load the route file.
    require('./' + file)(app);
  });
};
```

With that module, creating a new route definition and implementation is really easy. For examples, `hello.js`:

```
function hello(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello world');
}

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.get('/api/hello_world', hello);
};
```

Each route module is **standalone**.

Comment: Do you use a generator to create this structure?

Comment: plus one for standalone services. that is missing a lot from many layout suggestions.

Answer (score 17):

I think it's a great way to do it. Not limited to express but I've seen quite a number of node.js projects on github doing the same thing. They take out the configuration parameters + smaller modules (in some cases every URI) are factored in separate files.

I would recommend going through express-specific projects on github to get an idea. IMO the way you are doing is correct.

Comment: Hi All,

In which folder I have to place the logger (winston)

i.e

src/logger
src/utils

Please suggest

Answer (score 17):

I like to use a global "app", rather than exporting a function etc

Comment: I opt to take advices from the creators :) BTW, could you please provide us with some code?

Comment: that's right. in this apps you see -  https://github.com/visionmedia/screenshot-app

Comment: could you pls explain

Answer (score 17):

it is now **End of 2015** and after developing my structure for 3 years and in small and large projects. Conclusion?

**Do not do one large MVC, but separate it in modules**

So...

**Why?**

- Usually one works on one module (e.g. Products), which you can change independently.
- You are able to reuse modules
- You are able to test it separatly
- You are able to replace it separatly
- They have clear (stable) interfaces

  -At latest, if there were multiple developers working, module separation helps

The [nodebootstrap](http://nodebootstrap.io/) project has a similar approach to my final structure. ([github](https://github.com/inadarei/nodebootstrap))

**How does this structure look like?**

1. **Small, capsulated modules**, each with separate MVC
2. **Each module** has a package.json
3. **Testing** as a part of the structure (in each module)
4. **Global configuration**, libraries and Services
5. Integrated Docker, Cluster, forever

Folderoverview (see lib folder for modules):

[image: nodebootstrap structure]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update the folder overview picture with the individual modules expanded as well, as an example of how you would structure those as well.

Answer (score 10):

I am giving MVC style folder structure please find bellow .

We used bellow folder structure for our big and medium web applications .

```
 myapp   
|
|
|____app
|      |____controllers
|      |    |____home.js
|      |
|      |____models
|      |     |___home.js
|      |
|      |____views
|           |___404.ejs
|           |___error.ejs
|           |___index.ejs
|           |___login.ejs
|           |___signup.ejs
|   
|
|_____config
|     |___auth.js
|     |___constants.js
|     |___database.js
|     |___passport.js
|     |___routes.js
|
|
|____lib
|    |___email.js
|
|____node_modules
|
|
|____public.js
|    |____css
|    |    |__style.css
|    |    
|    |____js
|    |    |__script.js
|    |
|    |____img
|    |    |__img.jpg
|    |
|    |
|    |____uploads
|         |__img.jpg
|      
|   
|
|_____app.js
|
|
|
|_____package.json
```

I have created one npm module for generation express mvc folder structurer.

Please find the bellow   https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mvc-generator

Just simple steps to generate and use this modules .

i) install module `npm install express-mvc-generator -g`

ii) check options `express -h`

iii) Generate express mvc structure `express myapp`

iv) Install dependencies: `npm install`:

v)Open your config/database.js , Please configure your mongo db.

vi)Run the application `node app` or `nodemon app`

vii)Check URL http://localhost:8042/signup OR http://yourip:8042/signup

Answer (score 9):

I don't think it's a good approach to add routes to config. A better structure could be something like this:

```
application/
| - app.js
| - config.js
| - public/ (assets - js, css, images)
| - views/ (all your views files)
| - libraries/ (you can also call it modules/ or routes/)
    | - users.js
    | - products.js
    | - etc...
```

So products.js and users.js will contain all your routes will all logic within.

Answer (score 7):

It's been quite a while since the last answer to this question and Express has also recently released version 4, which added a few useful things for organising your app structure.

Below is a long up to date blog post about best practices on how to structure your Express app.
http://www.terlici.com/2014/08/25/best-practices-express-structure.html

There is also a GitHub repository applying the advice in the article. It is always up to date with the latest Express version.
https://github.com/terlici/base-express

Answer (score 6):

Well I put my routes as a json file, that I read at the beginning, and in a for-loop in app.js set up the routes. The route.json includes which view that should be called, and the key for the values that will be sent into the route.
This works for many simple cases, but I had to manually create some routes for special cases.

Answer (score 6):

I have written a post exactly about this matter. It basically makes use of a `routeRegistrar` that iterates through files in the folder `/controllers` calling its function `init`. Function `init` takes the express `app` variable as a parameter so you can register your routes the way you want.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var controllersFolderPath = __dirname + "/controllers/";
fs.readdirSync(controllersFolderPath).forEach(function(controllerName){
    if(controllerName.indexOf("Controller.js") !== -1){
        var controller = require(controllersFolderPath + controllerName);
        controller.init(app);
    }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 5):

This may be of interest:

https://github.com/flatiron/nconf

> Hierarchical node.js configuration with files, environment variables, command-line arguments, and atomic object merging.

Answer (score 5):

http://locomotivejs.org/ provides a way to structure an app built with Node.js and Express.

From the website:

> "Locomotive is a web framework for Node.js. Locomotive supports MVC
>   patterns, RESTful routes, and convention over configuration, while
>   integrating seamlessly with any database and template engine.
>   Locomotive builds on Express, preserving the power and simplicity
>   you've come to expect from Node."

Answer (score 4):

1) Your Express project filesystem maybe like:

```
/ ...
/lib
/node_modules
/public
/views
      app.js
      config.json
      package.json
```

app.js - you global app container

2) Module main file (lib/mymodule/index.js):

```
var express = require('express');    
var app = module.exports = express();
// and load module dependencies ...  

// this place to set module settings
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

// then do module staff    
app.get('/mymodule/route/',function(req,res){ res.send('module works!') });
```

3) Connect module in main app.js

```
...
var mymodule = require('mymodule');
app.use(mymodule);
```

4) Sample logic

```
lib/login
lib/db
lib/config
lib/users
lib/verify
lib/
   /api/ 
   ...
lib/
   /admin/
      /users/
      /settings/
      /groups/
...
```

- Best for testing
- Best for scale
- Separate depends by module
- Grouping route by functionality (or modules)

[tj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/935045/tjholowaychuk) says/show on Vimeo interesting idea how modularize express application - 
[Modular web applications with Node.js and Express](http://vimeo.com/56166857). Powerful and simple.

Answer (score 4):

I recently embraced modules as independent mini-apps.

```
|-- src
  |--module1
  |--module2
     |--www
       |--img
       |--js
       |--css
     |--#.js
     |--index.ejs
  |--module3
  |--www
     |--bower_components
     |--img
     |--js
     |--css
  |--#.js
  |--header.ejs
  |--index.ejs
  |--footer.ejs
```

Now for any module routing (#.js), views (*.ejs), js, css and assets are next to each other.
submodule routing is set up in the parent #.js with two additional lines

```
router.use('/module2', opt_middleware_check, require('./module2/#'));
router.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'www')));
```

This way even subsubmodules are possible.

Don't forget to set view to the src directory

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'src'));
```

Comment: any link to github with such structure interested in seeing how routes, views and models are being loaded

Comment: I think everything is explained. Routes are just classic express routes. Views need to be loaded prefixed with module names, models need to be loaded by referencing relative path.

Comment: On my last line, I set the view to the src directory. So from here on, all views are accessible relative to the src directory. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 4):

Sails.js structure looks nice and clean to me, so I use MVC style structure for my express projects, similar to sails.js.

```
project_root  
|  
|_ _ app  
|_ _ |_ _ controllers  
|_ _ |_ _ |_ _ UserController.js  
|_ _ |_ _ middlewares  
|_ _ |_ _ |_ _ error.js  
|_ _ |_ _ |_ _ logger.js  
|_ _ |_ _ models  
|_ _ |_ _ |_ _ User.js  
|_ _ |_ _ services  
|_ _ |_ _ |_ _ DatabaseService.js  
|  
|_ _ config  
|_ _ |_ _ constants.js  
|_ _ |_ _ index.js  
|_ _ |_ _ routes.js  
|  
|_ _ public  
|_ _ |_ _ css  
|_ _ |_ _ images  
|_ _ |_ _ js  
|  
|_ _ views  
|_ _ |_ _ user  
|_ _ |_ _ |_ _ index.ejs
```

**App folder**    - contains overall login for application.
**Config folder** - contains app configurations, constants, routes.
**Public folder** - contains styles, images, scripts etc.
**Views folder**  - contains views for each model (if any)

Boilerplate project could be found here,
https://github.com/abdulmoiz251/node-express-rest-api-boilerplate

Answer (score 3):

This is how most of my express project directory structure looks.

I usually do a `express dirname` to initialise the project, forgive my laziness, but it's very flexible and extendable. PS - you need to get `express-generator` for that (for those who're looking for it `sudo npm install -g express-generator`, sudo because you're installing it globally)

```
|-- bin
    |-- www //what we start with "forever"
|-- bower_components
|-- models
    |-- database.js
    |-- model1.js //not this exact name ofcourse.
    |-- .
|-- node_modules
|-- public
    |-- images
    |-- javascripts
        |-- controllers
        |-- directives
        |-- services
        |-- app.js
        |-- init.js //contains config and used for initializing everything, I work with angular a lot.
    |-- stylesheets
|-- routes
    |-- some
    |-- hierarchy
    .
    .
|-- views
    |-- partials
    |-- content
|-- .env
|-- .env.template
|-- app.js
|-- README.md
```

You must be wondering why .env files? Because they work! I use `dotenv` module in my projects (a lot recently) and it works! Pop in these 2 statements in `app.js` or `www`

```
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({path: path.join(__dirname + "/.env")});
```

And another line to quickly set `/bower_components` to serve static content under the resource `/ext`

```
app.use('/ext', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components')));
```

It probably can be a fit for people who're looking to use Express and Angular together, or just express without that `javascripts` hierarchy of course.

Answer (score 2):

My structure express 4.
https://github.com/odirleiborgert/borgert-express-boilerplate

**Packages**

```
View engine: twig
Security: helmet
Flash: express-flash
Session: express-session
Encrypt: bcryptjs
Modules: express-load
Database: MongoDB
    ORM: Mongoose
    Mongoose Paginate
    Mongoose Validator
Logs: winston + winston-daily-rotate-file
Nodemon
CSS: stylus
Eslint + Husky
```

**Structure**

```
|-- app
    |-- controllers
    |-- helpers
    |-- middlewares
    |-- models
    |-- routes
    |-- services
|-- bin
|-- logs
|-- node_modules
|-- public
    |-- components
    |-- images
    |-- javascripts
    |-- stylesheets
|-- views
|-- .env
|-- .env-example
|-- app.js
|-- README.md
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to structure ur express app:

- In main index.js the following order should be maintained.

  > all **app.set** should be first.
  >
  > all **app.use** should be second.
  >
  > **followed by other apis with their functions or route-continue in other files**
  >
  > **Exapmle**
  >
  > app.use("/password", passwordApi);
  >
  > app.use("/user", userApi);
  >
  > app.post("/token", passport.createToken);
  >
  > app.post("/logout", passport.logout)

Answer (score 1):

Best Way To MVC Structure for ExpressJs Project with handlebar & Passportjs

```
- app
      -config 
        -passport-setup.js
      -controllers
      -middleware
      -models
      -routes
      -service
    -bin
      -www
      -configuration.js
      -passport.js
    -node_modules
    -views
     -handlebars page
    -env
    -.gitignore
    -package.json
    -package-lock.json
```

Comment: @sandro-munda please check