# How to handle multiple expressjs webs running on the same server

Tags: node.js, express

I found and answer here [How should I organize multiple Express servers on the same system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332865/how-should-i-organize-multiple-express-servers-on-the-same-system) and the best answer was this

```
express.createServer()
.use(express.vhost('hostname1.com', require('/path/to/hostname1').app)
.use(express.vhost('hostname2.com', require('/path/to/hostname2').app)
.listen(3000)
```

All ok before there, but how I should organize to handle the request of each site (app) ie myfirstdomain.com => myhost:3000 (=> means proxy) and myseconddomain.com => myhost:3000, well my real question its how I determine which request handles which app, since all request ie / have both of them in their routes.

This its the first app

```
var app = express.createServer();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('my first domain');
});
```

Then this its the second app

```
var app = express.createServer();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('my second domain');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not read well the code example there, the first param its the domain that will execute the app. I feel so fool!