# Multiple unique nodejs webservers running on the same machine

Tags: node.js, express, routes, webserver

I have several webservers running on a machine, and currently, in order to select which website you want to be served you must switch what port you are connecting on (domain:8000, domain:8001), however I really do not like this solution. My goal is to be able to connect via domain/process1, domain/process2 however the problem is the dns is always going to connect to domain:80 and then pass the route to express (What im using for the servers)

I am aware I could use express to control what code runs using

```js
app.get('/process1', (req, res)=>{
   process1.getRequest(req, res);
   next();
});
app.get('/process2', (req, res)=>{
   process2.getRequest(req, res);
   next();
});
```

However, this requires all of my processes are running in a single instance of nodejs. My hope would be to not have to modify any of my current webservers and just create a single new process that will run on port 80 and redirect traffic to the different local ports based on the route.

I have seen [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332865/how-should-i-organize-multiple-express-servers-on-the-same-system) however they have several domains whilst I only have a single domain. 
I also read a bit about a reverse-proxy/nginx, if at all possible I would love to stay within nodejs. Is it possible to create my own reverse-proxy in node?

Answer (score 1):

You can have single domain and still use a reverse proxy like nginx.

Take a look at this article https://medium.com/@samanbaboli/how-to-load-balancing-nodejs-apps-using-nginx-a3b4ceb7c782.

Ps: you do not have necessary to pay to use nginx. 
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/

Comment: Good to know that nginx is free, however for me an optimal solotion would be one that I can do the need to install new services on my machine. Can I create my own reverse proxy somehow in nodejs or using the built in tools in linux (ubuntu)?