# ExpressJS app structure with Mongoose Models

Tags: express, mongoose

I wonder where should my mongoose models go in the context of an ExpressJS application? I dont want to put everything into server.js/coffee. Is there an example somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in a directory called `app/models` and structure your application like this answer: [ExpressJS How to structure an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7350875/266795)

Answer (score 0):

I create a data/models.js module which exports the various models I'm working with. For example models.js:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("localhost", "databaseName");

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: "string",
  email: "string",
  password: "string"
});

exports.User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

That allows me to require models elsewhere in the app like this:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose")
  , User = require("../data/models").User
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be following :
models.js:
module.exports = mongoose.model(“User”, userSchema);

Server.js:
Const User = require(“../data/models”);