# How do I run app function like get and post defined in other file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have created a file which creates express middle-ware app.

I have defined the app function in a separate file.

How do I run the app function.

My `app.js` file

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const mysql = require('mysql')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const users = require('./users')
const app = express()
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.options('*',cors());

app.listen('3001' ,(err)=>{
  if(err)
  console.log(err);
  else{
    console.log('server is running on port 3001');
  }
})
module.exports.app = app
```

my other file has following contents and let say it is `my-other-file.js`

```
const app = require('./app')

//get request for all checklist details
app.get('/getallusers',async (req,res)=>{
  let sql =query('SELECT', 'users','user_deleted = 0', 'firstname,lastname,name,email,photo,admin')
  var results =await  dbQuery(res,sql)
  console.log(results);
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 200,
    message : `Found ${results.length} users`,
    users: results
  })
})
```

Comment: `node my-other-file.js`

Comment: I tried but getting error:    app.get('/getallusers',async (req,res)=>{
    ^

TypeError: app.get is not a function

Comment: See answer below

Comment: @RaghuSreeram pls check the answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `app.js` file you are doing a *named* export i.e.

```
module.exports.app = app;
```

This means when you import you need to be explicit:

```
const app = require('./app').app;
```

Instead, if you make `app` the *default* export i.e.

```
module.exports = app
```

Then you don't need to change how you require the file in `my-other-file`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to your question is by running following command

`node my-other-file.js`

if you change the

`module.exports.app = app`  to `module.exports = app` in `app.js` file

If you are looking for a folder structure guideline then following links will help you

[ExpressJS How to structure an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778245/expressjs-how-to-structure-an-application)

https://www.terlici.com/2014/08/25/best-practices-express-structure.html

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-write-a-production-ready-node-and-express-app-f214f0b17d8c

Answer (score 0):

When running a nodejs file using the CLI (`node myapp.js`) it will only run the file code. So you have to carefully organize your files to depends on each other in the correct way.

When calling the `require()` statement, node will run the required js code. So you will want to have a single js file that require all the others js files dependencies.

Thus, you can run your app as the following: `node my-other-file.js`. It will require the `app.js` file, run it, then run the my-other-file code, as you expect it.

But it might not be the order you intend, so you should import the `my-other-file` from the `app.js` and run the function it defines.

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const mysql = require('mysql')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const users = require('./users')
const declareEndpoints = require('./my-other-file')
const app = express()
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.options('*',cors());

app.listen('3001' ,(err)=>{
  if(err)
  console.log(err);
  else{
    console.log('server is running on port 3001');
  }
})
// Call the function from my-other-file
declareEndpoints(app)
module.exports.app = app
```

my-other-file.js

```
//export as function to be used from the main js file
export default function declareEndpoints(app) {
   app.get('/getallusers',async (req,res) => {
      let sql =query('SELECT', 'users','user_deleted = 'firstname,lastname,name,email,photo,admin')
      var results =await  dbQuery(res,sql)
      console.log(results);
      res.status(200).json({
         status: 200,
         message : `Found ${results.length} users`,
         users: results
      })
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**My Answer.**

App.js

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const mysql = require('mysql')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const users = require('./users')
const app = express()
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.options('*',cors());

// Don't call listen here
// app.listen('3001' ,(err)=>{
  // if(err) console.log(err);
//   else console.log('server is running on port 3001');
// })
module.exports = app
```

index.js - File called by node. Eg: node index.js

```
const app = require("./app.js");

const port = "3001";

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Started listening"));
```